# What is a difference between action,reducer and store in redux?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-actions

I am new to react/redux. I am trying to figure out how all the pieces in redux interact. The one thing giving me trouble is understanding the relation between actions and reducers,store.

Comment: I suggest you to go though this article https://medium.freecodecamp.org/understanding-redux-the-worlds-easiest-guide-to-beginning-redux-c695f45546f6

Comment: I see you’ve bountied this.  Is there anything in particular that’s lacking from the current answers?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's pretty simple when you think about it:

- ***Store*** - Is what holds all the data your application uses.
- ***Reducer*** - is what manipulates that data when it recieves an action.
- ***Action*** - is what tells reducer to manipulate the store data, it carries the name and (not required) some data.

**Reducer** is usually in a format of a switch statement, that switches between all possible **Actions** (Cases) and then manipulates the **Store** data based on action. When a reducer data changes within the redux, the properties in your components are changed and then the re-render occurs.

Answer (score 13):

- **Store** -> A Globalized state
- **Action** -> What you wanna do, eg: event click
- **Reducer** -> Describes how your action transfers state into the next state.
  It checks which action took place and based on the action it updates the store.
- **Dispatch** -> Way how we execute the action. eg: Dispatch the action to the reducer. Then reducer will check what to do and the store gets updated.

Answer (score 10):

**Store**
An Object that holds the applications state data

**Reducer**
A function that returns some state data. Is triggered by an action `type`

**Action**
An object that tells the reducer how to change the state. It must contain a `type` property. It can optionally contain a `payload` property

Comment: I want to add to "action", that the `type` property it contains is used by the reducer to determine the type of action that you take inside the reducer. The most common pattern for this is to accept the action as a parameter in the reducer, and use a switch statement on `action.type` to determine exactly what you want to do to the store (global state)

Answer (score 6):

The actions, reducers and stores are the three building blocks of redux.

**Actions**: Actions are the only source of information for the store. Actions have a type field that tells what kind of action to perform and all other fields contain information or data. And there is one other term called Action Creators, these are the function that creates actions. So actions are the information (Objects) and action creator are functions that return these actions.

**Reducers**: As we already know, actions only tell what to do, but they don’t tell how to do, so reducers are the pure functions that take the current state and action and return the new state and tell the store how to do.

**Store**: The store is the object which holds the state of the application.

I found this link to be particularly helpful - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-to-redux-action-reducers-and-store/

Answer (score 3):

Imagine a situation where you want your class based components to share data among each other. They may even bring changes to the data. One may provide data to others in the form of props. But it very difficult to keep track of the name of the props and the structure of data.

The **Store** actually simplifies this stuff. You set up your application architecture in such a way that the components will get their data from the supply what is known as the **Store**. Actually, the mechanism is so smart the component will re-render itself when the data changes since the components are all ears.

And **Actions** are nothing but the carriers of data from your application to the store.

And it is very difficult to articulate the concept of reducers. You may imagine a real store where one puts different stuff for future use. The store is of no use when the stuff is put haphazardly. One may spend hours inside but may not find anything. The **Reducers** in simple terms manage the way data is kept in store provided by the actions.

Answer (score 1):

according to [redux documents](https://redux.js.org/introduction/core-concepts):

- **store:** The whole global state of your app is stored in an object called store.
- **dispatcher:** To change something in the state, you need to dispatch an action. (and that is what dispatcher does)
- **action:** An action is a plain JavaScript object that describes the kind of change to make (as dictated by `action.type`) to the **store** and the relevant payload required for that change.
- **reducer:** to tie state and actions together, we write a function
  called a reducer. it’s just a (pure) function that takes state and action as arguments and returns the next state of the app.

for a deeper understanding look at the diagram in [this link](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/653#issuecomment-216844781).

Answer (score 1):

**Actions**: Actions are a plain JavaScript object that contains information. Actions are the only source of information for the store. Actions have a type field that tells what kind of action to perform and all other fields contain information or data.

Example :

```
function addTask(task) {
   
  return {
     
    type: 'ADD_TODO',
    task: task
  }
}
```

**Reducers**: As we already know, actions only tell what to do, but they don’t tell how to do, so reducers are the pure functions that take the current state and action and return the new state and tell the store how to do.

Example:

```
function task(tasks = [], action) {
   
  if (action.type === 'ADD_TODO') {
    return [...tasks, action.task];
  } else if (action.type === 'REMOVE_TODO') {
      return tasks.filter(task => task !== action.task);
    }
  return tasks;
}
```

**Store**: The store is the object which holds the state of the application.
[image]

ref: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-to-redux-action-reducers-and-store/